# Sorting list. What is wrong with my sorting method?

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I have a real headache with my sorting method. I don't know what can be wrong? I have checked sorting method millions of times and I still messed up with it.
Here are my code

```
struct Man{
    string name;
    string adress;

    bool operator < (const Man & next);
};

bool Man::operator < (const Man & next){
    return adress < next.adress && name < next.name;
}

struct SarV{
    Man duom;
    SarV *sekV;
};

struct SarH{
    string date;
    SarH *sekH;
    SarV *prV;
};

void Branch::Check(string code, int month){
    ofstream rf("Rezultatai.txt", ios::app);
    rf.setf(ios::left);
    SarH *d = pr;
    rf << "Data" << endl;
    while(d != NULL){
        SarV *v = d->prV;
        Print(rf, v, code, month);
        d = d->sekH;
    }
    rf.close();
}
```

Here are my sorting function

```
void Branch::Sort(){
    string temp;
    for(SarH *s = pr; s != NULL; s = s->sekH){
        for(SarV *p = s->prV; p != NULL; p = p->sekV){
            for(SarV *p2 = p; p2 != NULL; p2 = p2->sekV){
                if(p2->duom < p->duom){
                    //---------------------------------------
                    temp = p->duom.name;
                    p->duom.name = p2->duom.name;
                    p2->duom.name = temp;
                    //---------------------------------------
                    temp = p->duom.adress;
                    p->duom.adress = p2->duom.adress;
                    p2->duom.adress = temp;
                    //---------------------------------------
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So what's wrong with it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: I said that my problem is Sorting method.

Comment: @Mendinskis _'I said that my problem is Sorting method.'_ That's way not enough to ask a question here.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions and http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your operator is likely wrong.

Try this:

```
bool Man::operator < (const Man & next){
    if(adress < next.adress) return true;
    if(adress == next.adress) {
       if(name < next.name) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It is working now! All the time i was checking my sorting method THANK YOU!